# MySQL Try-Catch Stored Procedure - SQL Syntax Error 1064

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, mysql-error-1064

I'm trying to create a **try-catch type stored procedure** in MySQL:

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `SQL_TRY_CATCH` $$

CREATE PROCEDURE `SQL_TRY_CATCH`()
BEGIN
    DECLARE `_rollback` BOOL DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION SET `_rollback` = 1;
    START TRANSACTION;
    UPDATE `devices` SET 
        `cabinet` = '46',
        `name` = 'Test Device',
        `type` = 'Test Type',
        `u_size` = '27',
        `service_tag` = '35sdf35',
        `port_1` = '10.10.1.1',
        `drac` = '10.10.1.2',
        `notes` = 'Notes 1',
        `hd_info` = 'HD Info 2'
    WHERE `id`='45';
    IF `_rollback` THEN
        ROLLBACK;
    ELSE
        COMMIT;
    END IF;
END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

But, I get **this error below** every time I run it:

> Error # 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual
>   that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to
>   use near '

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `SQL_TRY_CATCH` $$

CREATE PROCEDUR
```

> ' at line 1

Can someone point me in the right direction of what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: you have too many semicolon in your script? Try removing semicolon after SQL_TRY_CATCH() and BEGIN START TRANSACTION

Comment: Remove the semi-colon after BEGIN

Comment: @Piyush I removed the semi-colons but I still get the same error. Maybe there is too much white-space?

Comment: @Daniel:- try modified answer

Comment: @Piyush You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near `'DELIMITER $$
  DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS 'SQL_TRY_CATCH';
  CREATE FUNCTION 'SQL' at line 1`

Comment: add $$ after drop function and remove semicolon? see mofified anser also..  like DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS `SQL_TRY_CATCH`$$

Comment: don't you need to specify a return type for functions? `RETURNS INT` for instance?

Comment: Yes I added `RETURNS INT` but now I get: `Explicit or implicit commit is not allowed in stored function or trigger.`

Comment: you should covert this to procedure. why would you use a function anyways; you're not returning any result from it.

Comment: @OzgurBar See updated OP.

Comment: @Piyush Yes, I removed the DROP statement and it ran but didn't update the table. I guess the SP had to be created before running the DROP statement.

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DELIMITER $$
   DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `SQL_TRY_CATCH`$$

   CREATE PROCEDU' at line 1

Comment: ok, try my updated answer, that procedure have drop statement with semicolon and $$

Comment: use this   DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `SQL_TRY_CATCH`;$$

Comment: @Piyush See updated OP.

Answer (score 1):

you have too many semicolon in your script? Try removing semicolon after `SQL_TRY_CATCH()` and `BEGIN` and `START TRANSACTION` and also add return type for function  `RETURNS VARCHAR` or `RETURNS INT` or whatever you want

```
    DELIMITER $$
    DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS `SQL_TRY_CATCH`$$
    CREATE FUNCTION `SQL_TRY_CATCH`() RETURNS INT
    BEGIN
        DECLARE `_rollback` BOOL DEFAULT 0;
        DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION SET `_rollback` = 1;
        START TRANSACTION;
        '.$sql.';
        IF `_rollback` THEN
            ROLLBACK;
        ELSE
            COMMIT;
        END IF;
    END$$
    DELIMITER ;
```

**UPDATE**

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `SQL_TRY_CATCH`;$$

CREATE PROCEDURE `SQL_TRY_CATCH`()
BEGIN
    DECLARE `_rollback` BOOL DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION SET `_rollback` = 1;
    START TRANSACTION;
    UPDATE entities SET `slug`='servers' WHERE `slug`='devices';
    IF `_rollback` THEN
        ROLLBACK;
    ELSE
        COMMIT;
    END IF;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```